# unwrapping nullable<T> to get T in IValueConverter

Tags: c#, type-conversion, ivalueconverter

I'm currently writing a converter which should parse a string as an long/int/short and store the value in a bound variable.

The problem I am encountering is that Convert is easy, I return a string, but ConvertBack requires the exact type (e.g. returning long to a short binding will just fail, instead of truncating).  That being said our data source uses all 3 data types (+nullable), and I don't want to write 3 copies of the converter, and use them properly, I'd rather have a smarter converter. For now my code looks as follows (the part remaining is the TODO):

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  var stringValue = value as string;
  var parsed = long.TryParse(stringValue, out long longValue);
  if (ValueTypeHelper.IsNullableType(targetType))
  {
    if (!parsed) return null;
    // TODO: this should unwrap the nullable Nullable<int> -> int
    //targetType = targetType.MemberType.GetType();
    // EDIT: The working version is below:
    targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
  }

  if (!parsed) return 0;
  if (targetType.Equals(typeof(short))) return (short)longValue;
  if (targetType.Equals(typeof(int))) return (int)longValue;
  return longValue;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? In your code I see: "working version". Does it already work?

Comment: Is this code not working? It's not clear what you want help with.

Comment: The `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` already does the unwrapping in terms of the type. And for the values it just works automatically when you unbox the result. An `object` *never* contains a nullable instance but you can always unbox its content as a nullable type.

Comment: I figured out it out just after posting, is it best to just delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago [I found this converter](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/07/09/a-universal-value-converter-for-wpf.html) and have been using it in situations similar to yours ever since:

```
public class UniversalValueConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // obtain the conveter for the target type
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);

        try
        {
            // determine if the supplied value is of a suitable type
            if (converter.CanConvertFrom(value.GetType()))
            {
                // return the converted value
                return converter.ConvertFrom(value);
            }
            else
            {
                // try to convert from the string representation
                return converter.ConvertFrom(value.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return GetDefault(targetType);
            // return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            // return null;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
        try
        {
            // determine if the supplied value is of a suitable type
            if (converter.CanConvertFrom(value.GetType()))
            {
                // return the converted value
                return converter.ConvertFrom(value);
            }
            else
            {
                // try to convert from the string representation
                return converter.ConvertFrom(value.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return GetDefault(targetType);
            // return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            // return null;
        }
    }

    private static UniversalValueConverter _converter = null;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (_converter == null) _converter = new UniversalValueConverter();
        return _converter;
    }

    public UniversalValueConverter()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public static object GetDefault(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

to use use in xaml:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyConvertersNamespace"

....

<TextBox="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Converter={converters:UniversalValueConverter}}"/>
```